# How can I explore the PanNuke dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am using PanNuke: An Open Pan-Cancer Histology Dataset for Nuclei Instance Segmentation and Classification

Here I have found `masks.npy`, an array of approximately 10 GB, shape (2656, 256, 256, 6). Now I want to explore it to look inside data. How can I do this?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
import glob, os
import skimage.transform as st
import keras

img_array = np.load('/content/drive/My Drive/masks.npy')
print (img_array.shape)
```

(2656, 256, 256, 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are new in python, the first procedure is understand your dataset.
For this multidimentional array 2656 is the number of records in the array (2656 mesurements). 256 and 256 Are two dimensions to draw the image (like numerical values for pixels in some squared picture). And the last dimension: 6, defines nuclei classification: Epithelial, Inflam, Malignat, Necrotic, Str, Non-nuclei.

There is more than one way to have the insights for this dataset (numerical and graphical), to learn how to deal with biomedical images you could try this: https://learn.datacamp.com/courses/biomedical-image-analysis-in-python